# Call a function imediatly before another is call

Tags: javascript

I'm using a library and what I'm trying to do is, every time a function on the library is called, I want to call first my function.

Let's see the code bellow where the problem is recreated to became more understandable:

```js
var valueToConsole = 1;

function A(){
   console.log(valueToConsole)
}

function B(){
   valueToConsole = 2;
   A();
   valueToConsole = 1;
}

A();
```

What I want is a way that I could console the "2" value without need to change or overwrite the function A. I'm seeking a way that every time that the function A is called, before their execution, I want execute the function B();

We can accoplish that it java by using [AspectJ](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/). I'm hopping that we have something similar in javascript.

Note:
A pure javascript solution, if possible, it will be appreciated.

Comment: So… you want to change the behaviour of `A` without changing anything about it or wrapping it?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Ryan Is not really change the behavior but is similar to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every time a function on the library is called, I want to call first my function.

You can override the function of library in a way that it calls your function first followed by library's function.

#### Logic

- Create a variable that will hold reference to original function.
- Now override the lib's function. Call your function and the call above variable that holds the ref.

**Sample:**

```js
var utils = (function(){
  function printHead() {
    console.log('*'.repeat(25));
  }

  function print(str) {
    printHead();
    console.log(str);
    printHead();
  }
  
  return {
    print: print
  }
})();

utils.print('Hello World');

function customHead(){
  console.log('='.repeat(25));
}

var dummy = utils.print;

utils.print = function(){
  customHead();
  dummy();
  customHead();
}

utils.print('Hello World');
```

Comment: Seems the same as in my answer, except you forgot to pass arguments and was not going to pass `this`.

Answer (score 0):

No you only can override the funtion. But you can call the old implementation inside.

I'll show example with jQuery `find` function, but you can use same approach for any function including global ones.

```js
(function () {
  var old = $.fn.find;
  
  $.fn.find = function () {
    console.log(arguments);
    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();

console.log($("body").find("script").attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For those who thinks my code uses jQuery: **no it doesn't**.
The same example with patching an other thing:

```js
var lib = {
  doInner: function (x) {
    return 38 + x;
  },
  doSmth: function (x) {
    return this.doInner(x * x);
  },
  doOther: function (x, y) {
    return this.doSmth(x - y);
  }
};

(function () {
  var old = lib.doSmth;
  
  lib.doSmth = function () {
    console.log(arguments);
    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();

console.log(lib.doSmth(2));
console.log(lib.doOther(8, 6));
```

Comment: This is not really what I want.

Comment: @RicardoRocha, than what do you want?

Comment: I asked (if was possible) a solution in pure javascript. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @RicardoRocha, but this solution is in pure javascript. Why do you think, it's not pure? jQuery is used as smth to be overrided, not as a lib to override the othe thing.

Comment: When I asked a pure javascript solution, want I meant was that I don't want to create a dependency to any library. And seems that your code uses Jquery.

Comment: @RicardoRocha, no my code does not use jQuery. jQuery here is a sample of anything you want to patch. It's never used, it's just patched and singl line inside of console.log shows, that patching works.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class with the function in it, and call the console.log in the constructor:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        console.log('A')
    }

    myFunc(arg) {
        console.log(arg)
    }
}

let exampleInstance = new Example();//logs A
exampleInstance.myFunc('hello');// logs hello
```

Comment: This is not even close what I'm pretending. Maybe the question was not clear. I made some change. Can you please check again?

Comment: How are you calling the 3rd party lib?